# jQuery loses reference to cached element once class is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my example code, the `subnav` variable is supposed to cache a reference to `ul.nav-categories` DOM object, but it gets lost after the class is removed.

```
<ul class="nav-categories">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$subnav = $('ul.nav-categories');

if (*some condition*) {
    $subnav.removeClass('nav-categories');
} else {
    $subnav.addClass('nav-categories'); 
   /* ^^^^ at this point $subnav becomes undefined in jQuery addClass function, 
   shouldn't it save a reference to the object and not 'ul.nav-categories'??? 
   Am I caching ul reference incorrectly? */
}
```

Comment: show some html it will helpful

Comment: You have not posted enough code. What makes you think that "$subnav" becomes undefined?

Comment: If the assignation and the condition are in the same function, it isnt properly cached.

Comment: Seems to be working here just fine http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/mvRBb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$subnav` can not become `undefined` in the specified code. But I suppose your fragment of js code is wrapped in some kind of function, and is called more than once.

Probably, it's called 1st time and removes class `nav-categories`.

Then it's called 2nd time, and attempts to get `$('ul.nav-categories');`

But that element already dont have class `nav-categories`.

So `$subnav` becomes `undefined`, because jQuery can't find node to set it.

Comment: thanks, yes the code was wrapped in a function which got called twice and of course the local var $subnav got destroyed at that point

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<ul class="nav-categories flag">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

$subnav = $('ul.flag');

if (*some condition*) {
    $subnav.removeClass('nav-categories');
} else {
    $subnav.addClass('nav-categories'); 
}
```

The only condition is : don't remove the class "flag" or u can just use only $subnav = $("ul")

Why : if you are evaluating that condition many times, the first time JQuery will find the object and will remove the class, but all the other times the object $("ul.nav-categories") will not exist anymore.

Hope this help you ;)